# how 2 iterate combined variable in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script, csv

I m new to shell script

```
file1='/home/ashish/Desktop/wipro/NSE_F_CMN_ORDTRD_08052020_01_01.csv.gz'

file2='/home/ashish/Desktop/wipro/NSE_F_CMN_ORDTRD_08052020_01_02.csv.gz'

a=1

while [ $a -lt 3 ]

do

    b="file$a"
    echo $b
    cksum $b
    a=`expr $a + 1`

done
```

I want iterate file1 & file 2 but I'm getting error No such file or directory

Comment: What does the file extension .gz stand for?

Comment: In bash you can increament a variable that way: `((a++))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to iterate your files, there are much simpler ways:

#### Iterate the list of files directly:

You can iterate the list of files obtained with a pattern, which is usually the best way :

```bsh
for file in /home/ashish/Desktop/wipro/NSE_F_CMN_ORDTRD_08052020_01_??.csv.gz
do
    cksum $file
done
```

Note that the wildcard characters ("*" and "?") are not seen as such if they are in a quoted string, so if you need to quote your file names (because they can contain spaces for instance), then you have to take the wildcards out:

```bsh
for file in "/home/ashish/Desktop/wipro/NSE_F_CMN_ORDTRD_08052020_01_"??".csv.gz"
do
    cksum $file
done
```

#### Generate the sequence of numbers and then iterate it

You can create a list of numbers and then substitute these numbers in a file name. If you know the numbers in advance, you can generate the list with brace expansion:

```bsh
for i in {00..04}
do
    file="/home/ashish/Desktop/wipro/NSE_F_CMN_ORDTRD_08052020_01_${i}.csv.gz"
    cksum "$file"
done
```

You can also use the brace expansion to generate file names directly:

```bsh
for file in "/home/ashish/Desktop/wipro/NSE_F_CMN_ORDTRD_08052020_01_"{01..03}".csv.gz"
do
    cksum "$file"
done
```

If you don't know the start and stop values when writing the code (these numbers are in variables) you can use `seq` to generate the list (the `-f` parameters pads the number with zeroes on the left):

```bsh
for i in $(seq -f "%02.0f" 1 4) 
do
    cksum "/home/ashish/Desktop/wipro/NSE_F_CMN_ORDTRD_08052020_01_${i}.csv.gz"
done
```

If you want to compute the sequence yourself, in bash you can increment numbers with:

```bsh
((a++))
```